# View page by wordpress admin only

Tags: php, wordpress

**Hi
I created a page with php and I want that page to be visible only to the WordPress admin
How do I do this?**

Comment: change visibility from public to private or with password.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`is_admin()` function checks if the current user is admin
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/

put this in your template:

```
<?php

if (is_admin())
{
    echo "Visible to admins only!";
}else{
    header("redirect:/")
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_admin() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\result.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\result.php on line 2

Comment: is_admin() is only for administrative interface page.
if(!is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('manage_options') && is_page(page_id)) { restrict } else { i am admin }